# My codename is not updating when I do it via netbeans

Tags: netbeans-7, codenameone, netbeans-plugins

My codename one is not updating when I run the update from the Netbeans plugins update option. It does the whole update process but once it finishes and restarts I find it still set to the old version and asking for an update. Am using Netbeans 7.4 and trying to update from version: 1.0.78 to version: 1.0.79.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with .79. It shouldn't be a problem since that version is only a minor bug fix release for older versions of NetBeans.

Comment: Ok thank you...was worried I was missing out on all the new good stuff.